# Prove lines being parallel within a traiangle

Tags: geometry, education

Here is the problem: The only condition given is $DF//BC$, is it possible to prove that $GH//BC$? Please verify it. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Obviously not, if that is the only condition given. (You can exaggerate what you don't know by moving $G$ and $H$ along the given lines.) On the other hand, if G and H are midpoints...

Comment: Without knowing how $G$ on $DE$ and $F$ on $FE$ are chosen, I don't see how you could.  If they're chosen arbitrarily, they clearly don't have to be parallel.  Isn't there any other information about $G$ and $H$?

Comment: Thanks two. I am also wondering if the question is well formulated. If $G$ and $H$ are midpoints of $DE$ and $EF$, then we can apply mid-point theorem (http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/geometry/polygons/the-midpoint-theorem) to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! $GH||BC$ Now since $G$ is midpoint of $DE$ and $H$ is midpoint of $EF$.

${\bf Claim}: \bigtriangleup DEF ~\&  \bigtriangleup GEH$ are similar

Since $\frac{DE}{GE}=\frac{FE}{HE}$

and $\angle DEF=\angle GEH$.

and therefore from Side-Side-angle similarity theorem both the triangles are similar and hence $GH||BC$.

Comment: Thanks but the original question does not say that $G$ and $H$ are midpoints of $DE$ and $EF$.

Comment: okay ! then you can not say that these two are parlell

Comment: From proof given above says that they are parlell iff they are mid points. I think now you have understood.

Comment: @absolutefriend I think you're using "iff" wrongly in this context. The line segments are certainly parallel *if* they are midpoints, but not *only if*. There are other possible positions for the points for the line segments to remain parallel. All that is needed is for $G$ and $H$ to be "proportionally" sited along their respective sides.